# Minimum of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

If $\bf{A}$ is a real symmetric matrix, we know that it has orthogonal eigenvectors. Now, say we want to find a unit vector $\bf{n}$ that minimizes the form:
$${\bf{n}}^T{\bf{A}}\ {\bf{n}}$$ 
How can one prove that this vector is given by the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $\bf{A}$?

I have a proof of my own, but it's rather unelegant - how would you go about proving this?

Comment: orthogonally diagonalize $A$

Comment: Equally interesting: What vector $x$ maximizes $x^tAX$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A=UDU^T$ be its eigen decomposition. Then $D$ is a diagonal matrix with all the eigenvalues as diagonal entries. Then we have
\begin{align}
\min_{n^Tn=1}~n^TAn\\&=\min_{u^Tu=1}u^TDu ~~~\{u=Un\} \\
&=\min_{x\in\mathbb{S}}\sum_{i}x_iD_{ii}~~~~~~~~~ 
\end{align}
where $$\mathbb{S}=\{(x_1,\dots,x_N)\in\mathbb{R}^N\mid x_i\geq 0,~~\sum_{i}x_i=1\}$$
The last step is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{S}}\sum_{i}x_iD_{ii}=\min_{i}D_{ii}
\end{align}
and also note that 
\begin{align}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{S}}\sum_{i}x_iD_{ii}=\max_{i}D_{ii}
\end{align}

Comment: Where does the equivalence come from?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i}x_iD_{ii}$ is a convex combination of set of numbers $D_{ii}$ on the real line. Thus it stays between the largest number and the smallest number.

Answer (score 13):

Proof that the minimum value of the quadratic form $n^T A n$ is the minimum eigenvalue of a real symmetric matrix $A$ for a unit vector $n$:

Let $A=UDU^T$ be its eigen decomposition. Then $D$ is a diagonal matrix with all the eigenvalues as diagonal entries. Let $D_{ii} = \lambda_i$Then we have
\begin{align}
\min_{|n|=1}~n^TAn\\&=\min_{|n|=1}~n^T(UDU^T)n\\&=\min_{|n|=1}~(U^Tn)^TD(U^Tn)\\&=\min_{|U^Tn|=1}(U^Tn)^TD(U^Tn) ~~~\tag{1} \\
&=\min_{|y|=1}~y^TDy, y:=U^Tn\\
&=\min_{|y|=1}\sum_{i}y_i^2D_{ii}\\
&=\min_{|y|=1}\sum_{i}y_i^2 \lambda_{i}~~~~~~~~~ 
\end{align}

Let $\lambda_j := \min \{\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n\} = \min_i \{\lambda_i\}$ for some $j = 1, ..., n$.

Observe the following lower bound for the quadratic form

$$\sum_{i}y_i^2 \lambda_{i} \ge \sum_{i}y_i^2 \lambda_j = \lambda_j \sum_{i}y_i^2 = \lambda_j (1) = \lambda_j \tag{2}$$

- This is actually the greatest lower bound, i.e. infimum, because the RHS of $(2)$ [does not depend on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739491/taking-limits-of-both-sides-of-inequality-in-royden-and-fitzpatrick) $y$: for any $y$, the quadratic form is greater than or equal to $\lambda_j$.
- This is actually the minimum because the quadratic form can achieve the infimum for $y$ s.t. $y_j=1$ and $y_i=0$ for the $i$'s that aren't $j$ ($\forall \ i \ne j$).

QED

---

By the way if $A^T=A^{-1}$, then $\lambda_j=-1$ because [Can we prove that the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix are $\pm 1$ by only using the definition of orthogonal matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562406/can-we-prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-an-n-times-n-orthogonal-matrix-are-pm-1)

---

$(1)$ Observe that $|U^Tn|=1$ because $|n|=1$.

Pf: $$|U^Tn|=(U^Tn)^T U^Tn = n^T U U^T n = n^T (I) n = n^T n = |n| = 1$$ QED

Answer (score 3):

For a symmetric matrix A, there exists a diagonal matrix D and an orthonormal matrix S such that $S^{-1}AS=D $ where the diagonal entries of D are the eigenvalues of A and the rows of S are the eigenvectors of A. so if we let $n $ be the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue of A then $n^TAn=\lambda $

To push this proof further;

A unit eigenvector $v$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda $ satisfies;

$Av=\lambda v \Rightarrow v^TAv=\lambda$

Comment: and why is this the minimal value of $n^TAn$?

Comment: @ellya - that doesn't quite answer the question, though I think I see how a proof could be completed from there.

Comment: @ellya surely, the eigen vectors of $A$ must be placed in the **columns** of $S$

Comment: Yes Brad, I think you're right, I forgot it was $S ^ { - 1 } $ on the left.