# Is ${\bf x^TAx} \ge { a \bf x^Tx}$ for some $a>0$ not dependent on $\bf x$ if $\bf A$ is positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a theorem saying ${\bf x^TAx} \ge { a \bf x^Tx}$ for some $a>0$ not dependent on $\bf x$ if $\bf A$ is positive definite matrix? If there is, can some help provide a reference or some explanation? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if there is a theorem, but if $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite and its eigenvectors span the space of $\mathbf{x}$ then it should be easy to show that such an $a$ exists and is the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: If $A$ is a $d\times d$ positive-definite matrix, then the map $x \mapsto x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax$ takes only positive values on the unit sphere $S^{d-1}$. By the compactness of $S^{d-1}$, this map has a positive minimum $a$ on $S^{d-1}$. Can you show that this proves your claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing $A=P \Lambda P^T$ (orthogonal diagonalization) we get

$$ x^TAx = y^T D y = \sum \lambda_i y_i^2$$

where $ y = P^Tx$ and $\lambda_i >0$ (assuming the matrix is strictly def pos).

Also $x^Tx = y^T y = \sum y_i^2$.

Hence $$ x^TAx = \sum \lambda_i y_i^2 \ge \sum \lambda_{m} y_i^2 = \lambda_{m} x^Tx $$ where $\lambda_{m}>0$ is the minimum eigenvalue.

This is normally written as

$$ \lambda_{m}\le \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x} \le \lambda_M $$

(See [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)  - see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728037/minimum-of-a-quadratic-form) )

So your conjecture is right, with $a=\lambda_{m}$ . But only if the matrix is strictly positive definite.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is a symmetric matrix?  Is that indicated in the question in some way?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Under the standard defitinion, positive definite matrices are symmetric.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question, never mind.